# How to enable logs specific to Garbage collector in dalvikVM

Tags: android, garbage-collection, dalvik

As mentioned I am trying to enable GC specific logs in dalvik virtual machine . How can i do this ?

When i say GC specific logs i want to moniter all function calls that happens in GC (not just gc fiter in logcat which results in GC_EXPLIIT and GC_CONCURRENT and GC_FOR_ALLOC only)so that i can make a flow chart (which process called GC which algo of gc is called based on heuristics etc).

I tried using `adb shell dalvikvm [options] .`

Is there any optiion like -XX:+PrintGCDetails(of jvm) in Dalvik virtual machine ?

Is there any flag in android framework codebase ,if set will print gc logs all the time ?

what does following option of dalvikvm do ? (A good online reference would work )

-Xgc:[no]precise
-Xgc:[no]preverify
-Xgc:[no]postverify
-Xgc:[no]concurrent
-Xgc:[no]verifycardtable
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC .

Answer (score 1):

I don't find a detail documents for these options.

After reviewing the source code, these options are:

- precise: VM thread stack each item may be only integer or internal values or an object pointer. And for registering these information, there is a register map for stack thread to mark the item's status. If it is open, only object will be marked which is called precise/no-caution GC
- xxx-verify: For vm GC verify step
- concurrent: Open/Close GC concurrent marksweep step
- ExplicitGC: Open/Close java API Runtime.gc() or signal GC.

And following is the details:

In dalvik source code, these options are used to configure the dalvikvm GC:

```
} else if (strncmp(argv[i], "-Xgc:", 5) == 0) {
    //In VM thread, there is a register map for marking each stack item's status whether it is an object or internal value. And In GC step, only object item will be marked. If this value is OFF, all stack will be marked even if the item is only an integer.
    if (strcmp(argv[i] + 5, "precise") == 0)
        gDvm.preciseGc = true;
    else if (strcmp(argv[i] + 5, "noprecise") == 0)
        gDvm.preciseGc = false;
    //Only for GC verify check
    else if (strcmp(argv[i] + 5, "preverify") == 0)
        gDvm.preVerify = true;
    else if (strcmp(argv[i] + 5, "nopreverify") == 0)
        gDvm.preVerify = false;
    else if (strcmp(argv[i] + 5, "postverify") == 0)
        gDvm.postVerify = true;
    else if (strcmp(argv[i] + 5, "nopostverify") == 0)
        gDvm.postVerify = false;
    //Open/Close Dalvik vm GC markseep is concurrent or not
    else if (strcmp(argv[i] + 5, "concurrent") == 0)
        gDvm.concurrentMarkSweep = true;
    else if (strcmp(argv[i] + 5, "noconcurrent") == 0)
        gDvm.concurrentMarkSweep = false;
    //Only for GC verify cardtable which is used for marking the concurrent marksweep dirty field
    else if (strcmp(argv[i] + 5, "verifycardtable") == 0)
        gDvm.verifyCardTable = true;
    else if (strcmp(argv[i] + 5, "noverifycardtable") == 0)
        gDvm.verifyCardTable = false; 
    else {
        dvmFprintf(stderr, "Bad value for -Xgc");
        return -1;
    }
    ALOGV("Precise GC configured %s", gDvm.preciseGc ? "ON" : "OFF");
}
```

PS:

For getting Android dalvikvm command options, you can input command `adb shell dalvikvm -h` for detail information.

And the result in Android 4.3(yakju-user 4.3 JWR66Y 776638 release-keys) is

```
dalvikvm: [options] class [argument ...]
dalvikvm: [options] -jar file.jar [argument ...]

The following standard options are recognized:
  -classpath classpath
  -Dproperty=value
  -verbose:tag  ('gc', 'jni', or 'class')
  -ea[:<package name>... |:<class name>]
  -da[:<package name>... |:<class name>]
   (-enableassertions, -disableassertions)
  -esa
  -dsa
   (-enablesystemassertions, -disablesystemassertions)
  -showversion
  -help

The following extended options are recognized:
  -Xrunjdwp:<options>
  -Xbootclasspath:bootclasspath
  -Xcheck:tag  (e.g. 'jni')
  -XmsN  (min heap, must be multiple of 1K, >= 1MB)
  -XmxN  (max heap, must be multiple of 1K, >= 2MB)
  -XssN  (stack size, >= 1KB, <= 256KB)
  -Xverify:{none,remote,all}
  -Xrs
  -Xint  (extended to accept ':portable', ':fast' and ':jit')

These are unique to Dalvik:
  -Xzygote
  -Xdexopt:{none,verified,all,full}
  -Xnoquithandler
  -Xjnigreflimit:N  (must be multiple of 100, >= 200)
  -Xjniopts:{warnonly,forcecopy}
  -Xjnitrace:substring (eg NativeClass or nativeMethod)
  -Xstacktracefile:<filename>
  -Xgc:[no]precise
  -Xgc:[no]preverify
  -Xgc:[no]postverify
  -Xgc:[no]concurrent
  -Xgc:[no]verifycardtable
  -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
  -X[no]genregmap
  -Xverifyopt:[no]checkmon
  -Xcheckdexsum
  -Xincludeselectedop
  -Xjitop:hexopvalue[-endvalue][,hexopvalue[-endvalue]]*
  -Xincludeselectedmethod
  -Xjitthreshold:decimalvalue
  -Xjitblocking
  -Xjitmethod:signature[,signature]* (eg Ljava/lang/String\;replace)
  -Xjitclass:classname[,classname]*
  -Xjitoffset:offset[,offset]
  -Xjitconfig:filename
  -Xjitcheckcg
  -Xjitverbose
  -Xjitprofile
  -Xjitdisableopt
  -Xjitsuspendpoll

Configured with: debugger profiler hprof jit(armv7-a-neon) smp show_exception=1
```